# shoutem/ui with expo fails to compile

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, expo, shoutem

Trying to scaffold a brand new Expo / React Native App with Shoutem/UI and I keep getting the same issue. I start by simply doing the following:

```
expo init myApp --template @native-base/expo-template-typescript
npm install --save shoutem/ui
npm start
```

Then I edit the App.tsx to only include the react code in the [UI toolkit introduction](https://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/introduction)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Examples } from '@shoutem/ui';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Examples />
    );
  }
}
```

Which results in the following

```
Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:19 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:39 in handleError
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:204:40 in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.1.232:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:211718:3 in global code
```

Comment: I think this is a version problem, try to check if the expo version is compatible with shoutem/ui ?

Comment: @DarkSide77 do you happen to know how to do that manually? shoutem/ui doesnt have any documentation about Expo at all sadly

Comment: you could run `expo doctor` in your root dir